# How to resume release upgrade after network interruption?

Tags: wireless, upgrade, 14.10, do-release-upgrade

When upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 14.10 via wifi (this is not a mistake, some modern computers come only with wifi), the connection was interrupted and reconnected within 1 second after downloading ca. 2.2 of 2.5 GB. 
The release upgrader shows a dialog that says something like "Updates could not be downloaded. The system upgrade was aborted". I am again connected to the internet. The dialog has a "close" button which will delete all downloaded files.

How do I resume the downloading of the upgrade packages where it stopped, or when starting from scratch, how do I preserve the already downloaded files? 
(Note: This is the second time this happens at exactly the same progress step.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was based on a misunderstanding. A previous upgrade failed because it predicted the not enough diskspace, and ubuntu-release-upgrader nudged me to do `sudo apt-get clean` which to make free space, which basically cleared all downloaded upgrade files.

I now found out that **ubuntu-release-upgrader preserves downloaded packages**. It is only confusing that the user has to close and restart the upgrader application and watch how it downloads again package lists (or something like that). After that, it continues downloading only the missing packages (like for me packages #2000–2550).